# What happens to Constitution bonus to HP when becoming a Lich?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, undead, hit-points, necromancy

I was about to Theorycraft a Wizard PC with the final goal to become a Lich but I am unsure about what happens to the bonus given from stats to HP.
When in Human form it comes from Constitution, but what happens when you transform?
Does the Constitution stat gets erased and the bonus then comes from Charisma?

My doubt is that it's useless to Theorycraft a Wizard dumping Charisma to 7/8 if you plan to become a lich because you'll lose a whole lot of hit points when you transform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Gone

You lose them and recalculate your HPs with your Charisma. Since you have Cha as a dump stat, yes, you will lose a LOT of HPs. Better line up those wish and headband...

The lich does not need as many HPs because its philactery allows it to return from final death so you can return to take your vengeance upon those pesky adventurers...

Comment: You seem to imply in the second paragraph that this benefit balances out the immense loss of hp, but considering that a sorcerer could have that *and* the immense hp benefit of Cha-to-hp, that’s not really so. Rather, as with most everything in Pathfinder, becoming a lich is something you have to plan for long, long before actually becoming one—and, in all likelihood, well before the thought ever crossed the character’s mind. The rules simply don’t allow for spontaneous character development, and the punishments for trying can be incredibly harsh. I suggest recommending GM flexibility.

Comment: Returning form the death is not an actual balance since you lose every piece of equipment previously owned

Comment: Does lichdom really need to be balanced though? Also, I'm pretty confident that lich's keep separate cache's of gear for just such an eventuality. Finally, I'm *very* confident that *PC*'s aren't supposed to achieve lichdom. Pathfinder operates under the assumption that PC's do not get racial hit dice or templates. That's not to say you can't, only that the rules/balance are *expected* to fall apart in that situation.